# Center vertically next to a float element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wonder if there is a pure elegant css solution to get a text next to a float element going under it when its height is higher than the float element BUT ALSO be centered when its height is lower than the float element. The 2 next images present what I want to obtain :
[image]
[image]

And there a coded version of both cases :

```css
.float {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#with_text_centered {
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

#with_text_centered p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>WITH TEXT UNDER THE FLOAT</h1>

<div class=ctn>
  <div class=float></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<h1>WITH TEXT CENTERED</h1>

<div id="with_text_centered">
  <div class=float></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I can so do each separately but can't find a way to do both (for responsive design purpose). The only solution I found for now require js (using ResizeObserver) and it seams odd to me to have to use some js in that case that seams pretty simple.

Also, I would for sure prefer to not have to hardly define height anywhere. In my exemple, I unfortunately define a height of 80px.In fact, in my version using js, I switch to a flexbox when the text is lower than the float element. It's easier and more elegant like this IMO to center the text. When I do so the float is ignored (flex are made to ignore float).

Comment: I'm 95% sure this isn't possible, but it's hard to know for certain.

Comment: @Alohci, with 75 views and none attempt of answer, I start to think that there is indeed no solution :'( . But thanks to everybody who tries !

Comment: @Alohci it's possible :) [let's hope it's cross browser and we don't have strange edge cases]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using an extra wrapper it's possible. The trick is to be able to use `top: 50%` which is not possible without a height reference. The use of flexbox will trigger the stretch alignment and will make the height definite and you can do it.

Nothing will happen in the first case because `top: 50%` will get negated by the translate since the text is defining the height.

```css
.float {
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div {
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  translate: 0 -50%
}
```

```html
<h1>WITH TEXT UNDER THE FLOAT</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class=float></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
      ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>WITH TEXT CENTERED</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div >
    <div class=float></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! That seems perfect. Nice work.

Comment: It's very cool. I was almost sure it was impossible.